# Proper scaling of drawables in horizontal scroll view?

Tags: android, icons, horizontalscrollview

I have a HorizontalScrollView that contains the icons of the apps installed on the user's device. The code reads as follows:

```
    for(int i=0; i<installedApps.size();i++){
        ImageView appIcon = new ImageView(this);
        Drawable drawableAppIcon = mPackageManager.getApplicationIcon(installedApps.get(i).applicationInfo);
        //drawableAppIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 55, 55);
        appIcon.setImageDrawable(drawableAppIcon);
        //appIcon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        listLayout.addView(appIcon);
    }
```

Where `installedApps` is an ArrayList of the PackageInfo of all installed apps on the device. The .xml is as follows:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewArcade"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listApps"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The problem with this is that when the app is run, various apps end up having various size icons with varying densities. I'm not particularly concerned about the density or resolution, because all icons for my case need to be shrunk to a size where you can't tell the difference. However I am having trouble figuring out exactly how to make all icons the same size. The first line I commented `drawable...` I thought would do the trick, the second commented line worked for me when I did something similar in a gridview but in this case, neither is doing it?

I also tried setting the layout_height of the LinearLayout to something like 50dp but that just resulted in icons being cut off since they are too big for the layout. So how can I shrink these icons?

EDIT: Managed to figure it out, I should have been editing the parameters of the ImageView, not the drawable, so the following worked:

```
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(55, 55);
appIcon.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: check drawableAppIcon.getIntrinsicWidth() and getIntrinsicHeight()

Answer (score 0):

Set the size to 0 0 55 55 again, but call appIcon.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

Check out some of the documentation for [setScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType%28android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType%29) and [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: Tried it, same general error, I think maybe I should be setting bounds on ImageView instead of Drawable?

Comment: Yeah, I thought you were setting the bounds on the ImageView because I just skimmed over the source.